# Using jquery is it possible to find and replace a string inside a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a script where it would replace my markers with the content I want on that marker.

For Example, I have this div:

```
<div class="panel panel-!{status}!">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"> !{title}! </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
            !{content}!
      </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the texts inside `!{status}!`, `!{title}!`, `!{content}!` using jquery.

Is it possible? Or is there a better way to do this than find and replace method?

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: Yes there are better ways.. Handlebars.js is one, Mustache.js is another.

Comment: it would be better to wrap tags around the placeholders and update the whole contents of just that little tag. as-is, rewriting in the middle of html breaks event bindings, allows non-well-formed possiblities, and is slow/flickery to update.

Comment: why can't you use selectors to target those elements? and change its text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can user the code as :

```
<div id="parentdivid">
    <div class="panel panel-!{status}!">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"> !{title}! </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
            !{content}!
      </div>

    </div>
</div>    

$(document).ready(function() {
    var contentDiv = $("#parentdivid").html();
    contentDiv = contentDiv.replace(/!{title}!/g, 'title data');
    contentDiv = contentDiv.replace(/!{status}!/g, 'status data');
    contentDiv = contentDiv.replace(/!{content}!/g, 'content data');
    $("#parentdivid").html(contentDiv);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k3syfvk5/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can use Handlebars.js
For demo, paste these here, http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

**Template:**

```
 <div class="panel panel-{{status}}">
          <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title"> {{title}} </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
               {{content}}
          </div>
    </div>
```

**JSON:**

```
{ "title" : "title here","content": "content here","status": "status here" }
```

**Output:**

```
<div class="panel panel-status here">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title"> title here </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
           content here
      </div>
</div>
```